# React native debugger not displaying the origin of the error

Tags: reactjs, debugging, react-native

Sometimes in react native debugger, the error shown is not pointing to the file and line of the error, instead it just points to ExceptionManager.

[image]

This makes it hard to find and debug the origin of the error.

How can I find the origin of the error?

Thanks.

Comment: Can you please post your code for more information. It already say this.toggleGestures is not a function.
May be there is some issue with the binding or function

Comment: Hi HarshMkadia, that's the problem, the error shown in react doesn't point to where "this.toggleGestures" is located. I can find it manually, but why react doesn't point to the exact file and line where the error is produced? this is what I want to solve, not this specific error.